# how to know if the file is being used in computer?

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream

how to know if the `C:\FOO\BAA\filename.extension` file is being used in computer using C#?

I tried it:

```
try { 
 var file = File.OpenRead(fileName); 
} catch { 
   // .. 
}
```

but it returns an exception only if the file is being by another process in current time. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "but it returns an exception only if the file is being by another process in current time" ... what do you mean then by "being used"? It can be used by another process, and this is where you get the exception.

Comment: Off topic, but related to your code sample: Don't ever do a blind `catch { /* ... */ }` without specifying the type of exception.  It is bad form as there are some exceptions you should never handle (such as `OutOfMemoryException`).  Instead only catch the exception types you specifically know how to handle, e.g. `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: @vucetica:when I say "being used",I mean if the file are open in windows currently.

Comment: @Jack and it can be opened only and only if some other process opened it, so if your code throws exception when file is opened by another process, then it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to determine if a specific file *has been used recently* then you could look into checking the [`File.GetLastAccessTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method. It'll tell you when the file was last accessed (assuming no one has messed with it).

Otherwise to determine if a file is *currently in use*, the code you posted should work.

Comment: @Steve - Sometimes you just don't know what these people are thinking.

Comment: when I say "being used",I mean if the file are open in windows currently.

Comment: @Jack - Then the code you posted should work. What's the problem?

Comment: what I need is something like:`Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process proc in processlist)
            {
                if (proc.MainModule.FileName.Equals(path))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }`

it given an exception: `win32Exception: acess denied`

Comment: @Jack - What does that have to do with your question? You probably don't have permissions. Perhaps if you describe (in your question) what you're trying to achieve we might be able to help you better.

Comment: @Jack I think you may be confused with the notion of a file `open in windows currently.` a text editor, for example, won't necessarily lock the file on the file system while the "file" is being edited. Often times a file is read into memory and edited there... then persisted to disk later.

Comment: @Steve:sorry, you are right. The right way is check it by Window title.